# Clarifying the following sentence of confusion using two alternating conjunctions and semicolon before and

Tags: punctuation, grammaticality-in-context

> Nearly 10 percent of readers came from Japan **;** **and** Australia, India **and** France all contributed a significant readership as well.

Two questions, why did the writer use semicolon before “and”?

Secondly, what is the purpose of using two conjunctions “and, and”?

Comment: So that the reader would not think "from Japan and Australia".  Those are two separate independent clauses. *After* reading them a reader would know how to parse them, but the goal of punctuation (or the absence of punctuation) is to provide real-time assistance, not assistance after-the-fact.

Comment: It is grammatical to put **and** before the final element in a list which forms the subject or object of a verb, and in lists generally.  *Moe, Larry, **and** Curly were a comedic trio known as The Three Stooges.*   *We went to the beach, to the mountains, **and** to the desert on our vacation.* In a way, **and** signals the list is about to come to an end.

Comment: What is the source?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence, as it stands, is incorrect. The first "and" should not be there, or else the semicolon should be replaced with a comma. This is because it is a compound sentence (two subjects, each with their own predicate) formed by combining these sentences:

> Nearly ten percent of readers came from Japan. Australia, India and France all contributed a significant readership as well.

Creating a compound sentence like this can be done in two ways; adding a comma and conjunction:

> Nearly ten percent of readers came from Japan, and Australia, India and France all contributed a significant readership as well.

Or using only a semicolon:

> Nearly ten percent of readers came from Japan; Australia, India and France all contributed a significant readership as well.

The author of the passage incorrectly used both a semicolon and the conjunction "and." If we maintain their decision to use a semicolon, the sentence would look like the example immediately above; in short, the reason you are confused by the two and's is that one of them does not belong there.